# Pygame Zero: How can I add a Surface to Pygame Zero after having the Player go "Gameover"

Tags: python, pygame-surface, pgzero

I am currently working on a game for a school project. Basically: The Character gets hunted by a rect that is constantly moving towards him. Now whenever it Collides I want a big red box to show up with the Text "Gameover" in the middle of the screen. However Rects can only be colored on the border and in the Pygame Documentation I don't understand what I first need to do to make a Surface work the way I want.

Now my question: How can I implement a red Surface to pop up once the character collides with the enemy to signal a "Gameover".

What I thought about was setting an "if" statement into the draw function that gets set true once a collision occurs to only draw the surface when the players goes Gameover.

Something like: (Incase anyone is wondering: "Tesbold" is the players character and "Follower" the object hunting the Player)

```
def draw():
    screen.clear()
    screen.fill((200,200,200))
    Tesbold.draw()
    Follower.draw()
    screen.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    if Gameover = True:
        (Draw Red Box with Text "Gameover" in the middle of the screen)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pygame Zero is built on top of Pygame and simplifies it. To draw rectangles and filled rectangles that contain text in Pygame Zero, please check the Pygame Zero documentation https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html. Create a rectangle using the Rect class and draw it with `screen.draw.rect` or  `screen.draw.filled_rect`. You can use the same Rect object combined with `screen.draw.text` or `screen.draw.textbox` to add text to the rectangle.

```py
WIDTH = 500  
HEIGHT = 500  
Gameover = True  
box = Rect((WIDTH-200)//2, (HEIGHT-100)//2, 200, 100)  
def draw():  
    screen.clear()   
    screen.fill((200,200,200))    
    # draw other sprites  
    if Gameover == True:  # note the '==', not '='  
        # draw the Rect and text  
        screen.draw.filled_rect(box, "red")  
        screen.draw.text("Game Over", center=(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2), color="white", fontsize=40)
```

Comment: While that link and the code you added in your answer is a good start, please add a full working example so that others are able to asses the validity of your suggestions. Thanks, and welcome to SO!